# Stop the provided router from hijacking my request to display it's own internal (No internet connection) page

Tags: windows, networking, macos, router

I apologize for the cumbersome title but I'm not sure how else to phrase the question.

The router is a Technicolor TG589vac.
The problem is that when the connection goes down the router redirects any requests to it's own internal ISP branded connection is down page.

My problem is two-fold

1. After you click reload and it finally decided to let the request go though, it only connects to the host, not the whole URL
2. Sometimes even after the connection is restored it sometimes gets stuck on that page whenever you try to access any URLS for that host even though I know the internet is back becuase other URL requests work fine

It also takes a relatively long amount of time to confirm that yes, the internet connection is back on.

So, without modifying the router is there anything (if at all) I can do to make this a less irritating situation?

Comment: Is the router also functioning as your DNS server?

Comment: Could be? I'm not sure and I don't have admin access.

Comment: Check the network settings on your PC/laptop. Is the DNS server the same as your default gateway?

Comment: I'm not sure, but for the sake of argument what would I do in either case?

Comment: What makes you not sure? Have you checked the network settings on your device?

Comment: Yes it is the same as the dns serv er is the same as the default gateway.

Comment: In that case, you could try changing the DNS server configured on your device (perhaps 8.8.8.8). Some ISP owned DNS servers will do their own custom DNS resolution to present to their customers.

Comment: Right, switched the Internet protocol to use `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4` for preffered and alternate DNS respectively. That should stop the router from hijacking the connection now right?

Comment: Sadly, it didn't completely work, whilst I received DNS errors via the normal browser page, when it reconnected it was still hi-jacked by the router, though this has only happened once since then. I guess this counts as a partial answer?